# What is the best database structure and relationships for this scenario?

Tags: database-design, laravel

I'm creating a website that has Post/Topics/Categories:

- A **Post** can belong to more than one **Topic**
- A **Topic** can belong to more than one **Category**
- and of course, a **Category** has many **Topics** and many **Posts**, and a **Topic** has many **Posts**

I hope this makes sense, What is the best MYSQL structure for this? 
I'm also using Laravel, so if you could explain the Eloquent relationships for this structure it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on some [Relational Database Design](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)

Here's an example:"

```
Categories table
Id
Name
...

Topics table
Id
Name
...

Posts table
Id
Name
...

Category_Topic Table
category_id    
topic_id

Topic_Post Table
topic_id
post_id
```

Read the [Laravel : Eloquent documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent) on how to create your Laravel models.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Migrations
Schema::create('categorys', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description;);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('topics', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('posts', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('imageable_type');
    $table->integer('imageable_id');
    $table->text('content');
            $table->timestamps();
})

// Models
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Topic');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Post', 'imageable');
    }

}

class Topic extends Eloquent {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Post', 'imageable');
    }
}

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}


// Very simple controller example which walks through the relationships and echos the content.
class ConversationController extends BaseController {

    public function conversations()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        foreach($categories as $category)
        {
            foreach($category->topics as $topic)
            {
                foreach($topic->posts as $post)
                {
                    echo $category->name;
                    echo $topic->name;
                    echo $post->content;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I misspelled `categorys` on purpose to better conform with Laravel's standards and to make things less confusing.

Comment: The problem with this method is that a post can't belong to more than one topic, which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: It can though.  It's a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: when I insert a new post, I set the imageable_type to "topic" and then set the imageable_id to the topic id, how can i add more than one topic to one post?

Comment: Okay, that's going to get very complicated pretty quick.  You'd need a `post_topic` table to manage which topics belong to which posts and which posts go with what product, then you'd add those ID's as the imageable_id in your `posts` table and I think the type would be `PostTopic` and you'd have to create a `PostTopic` model for that table as well.

Comment: This a little complicated for what I'm looking for, I've used a mix of one to many and many to many relationships and it works fine.
Thanks a lot for your help anyway